# How to download a file from FTP and stream it to client using PHP

Tags: php, ftp

When someone comes to my website via url: http://domain.com/FILE_ID, PHP would connect to the ftp server and get FILE_ID and then stream it to client without saving it on the local server. I don't want to provide my clients with a link to my file on ftp server instead I thought of this.

Does anyone have an idea how I can accomplish this?

I was thinking I could use "ftp_get()" method to get the file from ftp but that requires me to write in on a local server(or am I wrong?). After that use PHP headers to force the download.

Basically any and every piece of information would be useful. Just so I can start walking in the right direction.

Comment: afaik [`readfile()`](http://php.net/readfile) supports the ftp:// stream wrapper

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php#76483

Comment: Oh Great! Didn't know readfile() had support for ftp. Excellent! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are after is the Curl library - as it can handle FTP. [See this](http://www.linuxformat.co.uk/wiki/index.php/PHP_-_The_Curl_library), it has an FTP example.

Alternatively, if you've got a server that has URL bindings for file_get_contents, you can use

```
file_get_contents("ftp://username:password@server/path/to/file.ext");
```

to get the contents of a remote file on an FTP server.

Comment: Remember to set the headers properly before streaming the content to your user.